# Problems with Geth 1.8.19-stable

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets

I am trying to add static peers by `static-nodes.json` file but with this version it does not work. What is the way to do it ?

If I add peers with `admin.addPeer()` it works, but if I am using `--syncmode light` it doesn't.

Also, I am trying to use `--mine` in the command line and it does not work neither. It stops in `INFO [02-05|16:45:52.368] Commit new mining work`. It just runs if I add miner.start() in the console.

UPDATED: adding peers by static-nodes.json works but it doesn't if it is a light node

Answer (score 0):

Are you following this structure for your static-nodes.json file?
Is your file in the datadir directory? Can the user you are running geth with access to the datadir directory?

```
[
  "enode://a8ebedd431eda2cf7e8dffe684546b6f092fa14690e54350d012293c142d0c46b0ab984d64d469835ce5252be46519f452fe47333bfe0985a5baca09e1d92813@192.168.1.136:30303"
]
```

Did you try to connect it manually? Does it work?

```
admin.addPeer("enode://a8ebedd431eda2cf7e8dffe684546b6f092fa14690e54350d012293c142d0c46b0ab984d64d469835ce5252be46519f452fe47333bfe0985a5baca09e1d92813@192.168.1.136:30303?discport=0")
```

Is your port 30303 opened on your firewall? Can you reach it from outside?

About the miner, what happens? When you do --mine and you type eth.mining in your console, does it return false?
Is by any chance your node generating the DAG? Because it won't mine until the DAG is generated

Comment: I have added more datails in the question. The structure of the json file is the same. `eth.mining` is true, but the console is stuck on `Commit new mining work`. It does not happen if I use `miner.start()`